# Uncaught ReferenceError: (given function) is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

I am having issues getting a button click to call a function. In my code I tried 2 different ways of getting the button to call the function, no luck. Currently, am using onclick to call the function that simply logs a string, but I get a “Uncaught ReferenceError: camCapture is not defined” error in the console.

I think the issue may have to do with the order of script declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Campus Kitchens</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/codiqa.ext.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    #map{
    height: 225px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />

  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/codiqa.ext.js"></script>
  <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="js/campuskitchens.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad(){

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}


  function camCapture(){
      console.log("Over here!");
  }



</script>


  <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>
          Campus Kitchen
      </h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="camerainput">
        <button onclick="camCapture()" data-role="button">Capture Picture of Food</button>
        <img style="display:none; width:60px; height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

Full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4dqrhbft/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is (pointlessly) defined inside a "ready" handler, so it's not a global function.

Move the event handler out of that function. If you can't, because it relies on access to other symbols in the "ready" handler, then you'll have to change the way you set up the event handler (which you should do anyway) and do it with jQuery.

Comment: even after changing this, still no luck. See full code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwxfZTfyUF5kbVROdUFjVDI4eGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LeroyJenkins it works much better for this site if you set up your tests/demos on a site like CodePen, jsbin, or jsfiddle.

Comment: @LeroyJenkins make sure you check for errors in the console too.

Comment: Code site updated. Error in the console is in the title.

Comment: If it's not working in the fiddle, check the other answer - jsfiddle tries to do stuff for you, but sometimes that can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, change the second option from onLoad to No wrap - in <head>:

[image]

Otherwise, the `onLoad` and `camCapture` functions are not attached to the body or the button.

You'll then see "Over here!" in the console when you click the button.